# Import spacy shows SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Tags: python-2.7, conda, spacy

I am using the condo environment.

Full stack trace:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "utils_exp.py", line 10, in <module>
    import spacy
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/spacy/__init__.py", line 12, in <module>
    from . import pipeline
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/spacy/pipeline/__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from .pipes import Tagger, DependencyParser, EntityRecognizer, EntityLinker
  File "pipes.pyx", line 1, in init spacy.pipeline.pipes
  File "nn_parser.pyx", line 1, in init spacy.syntax.nn_parser
  File "morphology.pyx", line 1, in init spacy.morphology
  File "vocab.pyx", line 18, in init spacy.vocab
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/spacy/lemmatizer.py", line 24
    def __init__(self, lookups, *args, is_base_form=None, **kwargs):
                                                  ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Installed Spacy using PyPy.

Answer (score 1):

Solved the issue with this

```
 conda install -c conda-forge spacy
```